# How can I better save child objects of all objects in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, vue.js, object

so I created a project in Vue, and I a want to iterate through all of the ['monitors'] and save the different departues. How do I do this the best way?
Thanks!

```html
<script>

listOfAllTrips = this.wlData['monitors'][0].lines[0].departures;
listOfAllTrips2 = this.wlData['monitors'][1].lines[0].departures;
listOfAllTrips3 = this.wlData['monitors'][2].lines[0].departures;

</script>
```

Comment: `listOfAllTrips = this.wlData['monitors'].map(monitor => monitor.lines[0].departures);`

Comment: Thank you so much ritaj, this was exactly what I was looking for! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `map` and destructuring assignment as follow:

```js
let m = [{lines: [{departures: ["Ele", "Stack"]}]}, {lines: [{departures: ["Ele2", "Stack2"]}]}];
let result = m.map(({lines: [departures]}) => departures);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let listOfAllTrips = [];
 this.wlData['monitors'].map((data,k)=>{
    listOfAllTrips.push(data.lines[0].departures);
 })
```

Here is an iteration that uses the Ecma Script array mapping function which will take care of situations when the list of all trips is more than 3 as formally hardcoded.

Now to access each departure you just have to provide the access index e.g

```
listOfAllTrips[1]
```

this will return the second trip since the array index starts from 0